# How do we know that the Virial Expansion exists?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

How do we know that the [Virial Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_expansion) exists? How do we know that we may always write $\frac{p}{kT}$ as a power series in $\frac{N}{V}$? That is, how do we know that there exists $B_{i}$ so that $$\frac{p}{k_BT} = \rho + B_2(T) \rho^2 +B_3(T) \rho^3+ \cdots $$
where $ \rho = \frac{N}{V}$?

Comment: There are many proofs of convergence when the paremeters lie in suitable domains. See for example the classic book by Ruelle (I think that it's in Chapter 4): http://books.google.ch/books/about/Statistical_Mechanics.html?id=mNtWfcj_xhwC&redir_esc=y .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an semi-formal explanation.  Define $$f(N,V,T)=\frac{p(N,V,T)}{kT}.$$

While $f(N,V,T)$ is a function of $N,T$ and $V$, the variables $N$ and $V$ are partially redundant, and only the ratio $\rho=\frac{N}{V}$ is needed, since pressure is an intensive quantity. Thus we can write

$$f(\rho,T)=\frac{p(\rho,T)}{kT}.$$

Every smooth multivariate function admits a Taylor expansion, so we can expand in $\rho$ (and implicitly in $T$) as
$$f(\rho,T)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(T)\rho^n$$
and it suffices to make some assumptions about the nature of the coefficients.

Notice that $B_0(T)=0$ since $p\rightarrow 0$ as $\rho\rightarrow0$ (if there are no molecules present to exert force, there is no hydrostatic pressure).

Also notice that on physical grounds, in the limit as $\rho\rightarrow 0$, intermolecular interactions vanish and hence the 1st order term must reproduce the ideal gas law. As a result, $B_1(T)=1.$

As a result, we obtain the virial expansion $$\frac{p}{kT}=\rho+B_2(T)\rho^2+B_3(T)\rho^3+...$$